# facebook-like chat freichat integration code in php site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-chat

Freichat is a pretty famous script for facebook like chatting in any php site.

I think it is not any prob to post any freichat related question in SOF rather than in the forum of the mentioned script coz SOF is much more responsive, i think.

I just downloaded the [chat script](http://evnix.com/drupal2/) and pointed the browser to the directory and got the script installed, did customization from admin backend.

But my question is what is the necessary code snippet to get the chat working on a page?

I guess they call it freichatX code but I cannot find that anywhere?

Anyone there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer my self by asking at the freichat site . See [here](http://evnix.com/drupal2/node/445)